# SELECT from table WHERE value across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that maps products to categories. Each product can belong to multiple categories, so a product can have multiple rows with different category IDs. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_mid` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I want to get a list of all product IDs that are in category `A` that's simple enough-- but is there a way to get all `product_id`s where they belong to categories `A`, `B` *and* `C` as simply as possible?

Comment: The surrogate id column in this table seems to be redundant, as you appear to have perfectly satisfactory natural key on the remaining columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach is to do it with `HAVING` clause, not a `WHERE` clause. Group by `product_id`, and select rows having non-zero count of each of your three categories, like this:

```
SELECT product_id
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN category_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN category_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN category_id=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

The above statement selects `product_id`s of products that belong to all three categories with IDs 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 2):

It will be something like this:

```
select product_id from products_mid
where
category_id in (1,2,3)
group by product_id
having count(distinct category_id)=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM products_mid
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 3
```

This would find all products in categories 1 through 3, although a product could also belong to other categories.  If you want products which exclusively belong to category 1 through 3, and no others, then we would have to rephrase the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `intersect` operator to find the common values of three separate queries.

```
select product_id from products_mid where category_id = 1
intersect
select product_id from products_mid where category_id = 2
intersect
select product_id from products_mid where category_id = 3
```

Comment: Note: intersect is not available in MySQL, so not a good answer for this specific question, but I keep it because nearly all other database systems support it.